# Separable Differential Equation without x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

5y'= y(y+5)
Hi, I'm blocked on this differential equation.
The book suggests the separation method, but I don't know how to get the general equation in this specific case.
Thanks to all.
It's my first post thanks to anyone who considers it.
Sorry, I don't know how to use MathJax.

Comment: In this special case you can also use the methods of Bernoulli equations. Set $u=y^{-1}$, then $u'=-1-5u$ is a linear ODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $$\frac{dy}{y(y+5)}=\frac{dx}{5}$$